# Suspension points without some properties

Tags: javascript, jsx

How to use the suspension points without using some properties?

```
let foo = {
  color: 'red',
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  width: 100,
  height: 50,
}

let colors = {...foo} // removing width and height for this variable
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your exact needs but there are two easy things you can do. If you really want to delete the properties from the object, use delete.

```
let colors = {...foo};
delete colors.width;
delete colors.height;
```

Otherwise you can set them to null/undefined.

```
let colors = {...foo, width: null, height: null};
```